# Custom navigation bar in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller with a special font and a shadow image on it's navigation bar. However, when I segue to a different view controller, the new view controller mimics the navigation bar qualities of the view controller it was segued from. How do I get rid of this quality?

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold", size: 24.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "shadow")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the same style of navigation bar in all view controllers you should specify the navigation bar style in `AppDelegate`. In your case in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method add the following lines:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold", size: 24.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named: "shadow")
```

Now in all view controllers you will have the same navigation bar.